# Flex Mobile In-App Billing/Purchase

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I've looked all over and found nothing about this topic - For people making mobile app games and want to sell levels or potions or whatnot from within the app, is this supported on Flex mobile apps? Are there plans to introduce it? I've found info about advertisement implementation... is this a possible next step? Do you have to use something like PayPal instead of Android Market?

Sorry if this has been asked, but I haven't found anything yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind... 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491300/flex-mobile-supports-native-mobile-features

I dont have the reputation to answer/close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know Adobe said at GDC Conference they are in the process of analyzing requirements to make in-app purchases available via Flash Player API. It's almost a year so far since that announcement but there has not been any further news. The work around/the way most client-server implement these business rule is on the server-side where they implement an entitlements model.

Comment: I've done some searching around, any chance you could point me to a demo/tutorial of implementing this entitlements model on the server?

Comment: Essentially you need to develop your own CRUD application where clients will query to check if they have access or not (READ). If they don't have access, you will have to write business logic to enable them to have it (CREATE/UPDATE). If for some reason, they're is a chain of entitlements that need to be wiped out, there has to be a way to remove them at the root so child entitlements get swept away too (DELETE)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several native extensions that implement this functionality.

I have been using the ones from [Milkman Games](http://www.milkmangames.com/blog/tools/) with good results, and the support is fantastic. No financial association, just a very satisfied user.

There is also a free iOS Storekit ANE as well, although in my experience with it there are still some bugs, notably with blank receipt values for restored transactions: http://code.google.com/p/in-app-purchase-air-ios/

Note: implementing your own entitlements is ill-advised for various reasons:

1. Apple doesn't allow using anything other than their own in-app
   purchase API on iOS.
2. The various store implementations (well, Apple's
   and Amazon's at least, Google Play is another story) handle all of
   the details of international purchases and localized pricing for
   you.
3. The store implementations handle payments, subscriptions, durable purchases, and a host
   of other details that you will spend a lot of time getting right on your own.